# Having trouble writing an equation with scientific notation and exponents

Tags: python, scientific-notation, exponent

I am having some trouble writing this equation in Python and having it produce correct results:

> y = 2.957*10^-7 * x^4 – 2.343*10^-5 * x^3 – 1.67*10^-4 * x^2 + 0.04938 * x – 1.083.

I have tried the following code:

```
y = 0.0000002957*x**4 - 0.00002343*x**3 - 0.000167*x**2 + 0.04938*x - 1.083
```

and also:

```
y = (2.957*10**-7)*x**4 - (2.343*10**-5)x**3 - (1.67*10**4)*x**2 + 0.04938*x - 1.083
```

any advice would be helpful, I think the problem might be the scientific notation or the exponents and the way I am inputting them

EDIT
in response to questions, the equation spits out an incorrect number than what I get on a calculator

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: What trouble are you having? What do you expect it to produce? What does it actually produce?

Comment: the equation spits out the wrong number

Comment: Are you trying to create a function?

Comment: `(2.343*10**-5)x**3` needs to be `(2.343*10**-5)*x**3`, maybe? Also, note that Python understands scientific notation. `2.343e-5` works just as well as `0.00002343` or `2.343*10**-5`

Comment: @user15108227 **What do you expect it to produce? What does it actually produce?** Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre].

Comment: Apart from the `*` before `x**3`, there's also a missing `-` in `(1.67*10**4)`...*

Answer (score 1):

What you have can easily be converted to Python in a very direct way.  The equivalent Python statement (after fixing a flaw in the original equation...see below) is :

```
y = 2.95710e-7 * x**4 - 2.34310e-5 * x**3 - 1.67e-4 * x**2 + 0.04938 * x - 1.083
```

This involves only the simple substitution of the `^` characters, where you replace that character with `e` in the exponential floating point constants and with `**` for raising `x` to an integer power.
For reference to be able to more easily compare the source with the result, here's the original equation with the one slight fix mentioned below:

> y = 2.95710^-7 * x^4 – 2.34310^-5 * x^3 – 1.67^-4 * x^2 + 0.04938 * x – 1.083

UPDATE: Thanks to Pranav for pointing out a flaw in the source equation.  The term `1.67*10^-4` should be changed to `1.67^-4` to match the other similar terms, and the equivalent fix made to the resulting Python equation.  Those fixes were made and commented on above.

I always like to see what I'm working with in situations like this.  I used `matplotlib` to plot this function, using an unchanged version (except for the function and the bounds on `x`) of [this sample code](https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/python-matplotlib-plot-function.html).  Here's what I got for x values between -500 and 500:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering everybody.  The most helpful answer was using "e" instead of scientific notation (*10^x).